# Need help setting up a Makefile for an SDL C++ tutorial - Having trouble with linking object files

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to get a basic makefile running for an SDL C++ tutorial that I'm doing. I've done a bit of searching so far, and I've come up with a Makefile that will generate object files for my Main and my Graphics class as well as linking my Graphics header that is in a separate directory. I'm running into issues however when trying to link my object files to generate a program that I can run.
My directory is set up like so:

```
source
|__headers
|    |__graphics.h
|
|__object
|
|__src
|    |__main.cpp
|    |__graphics.cpp
|
|__Makefile
```

Makefile:

```
CC = g++
INC_DIR = headers
SRC_DIR = src
OBJ_DIR = object
COMPILER_FLAGS = -c -Wall -I$(INC_DIR)
LINKER_FLAGS = -lSDL2

SRCS = $(SRC_DIR)/main.cpp $(SRC_DIR)/graphics.cpp
OBJS = $(OBJ_DIR)/main.o $(OBJ_DIR)/graphics.o

DEPS = $(INC_DIR)/graphics.h

all : $(OBJS)

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp 
    $(CC) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) $(LINKER_FLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(DEPS)

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJS) all
    rm -rf SDLCS
```

Both my main.cpp and graphics.cpp have these includes:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include "graphics.h"
```

I'm able to generate object files for both main.cpp and graphics.cpp under my objects directory, but what do I need to modify in my makefile to generate a runnable program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a slightly more "canonical" GNU Makefile that does the job, the main points are:

- Make has a number of builtin variables and recipes (`CPPFLAGS` etc.), you don't have to emulate make's own usage when specifying your own variables and recipes but it might help other people who have to maintain your Makefile.
- Simply expanded variables (`:=`) can help avoid problems further down the chain, assuming you don't need recursive expansion (you don't here).
- GCC and Clang can both auto generate dependencies for you with the `-M` preprocessor flags as part of the compilation process.
- Targets that aren't actual files should be `.PHONY`.
- Since you're providing your own recipe and dependencies for compilation, using static patterns (`blah: %.o: %.cpp`) will make sure that other implicit rules are ignored, which has the added side effect of speeding up make. It won't make a difference here, and it might not always be what you need, but it's something to keep in mind.
- The last part after `include $(DEPS)` gets rid of some builtin stuff like remaking makefiles to speed things up, again it might not always be what you need and it won't make a difference in such a small project, but it's nice to know.

```
INC_DIR := headers
SRC_DIR := src
OBJ_DIR := object

CC       := g++
CPPFLAGS := -I$(INC_DIR) -MMD -MP
CXXFLAGS := -Wall
LDLIBS   := -lSDL2

SOURCES := $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.cpp)
OBJECTS := $(SOURCES:$(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o)
DEPS    := $(wildcard $(OBJ_DIR)/*.d)

.PHONY: clean

main: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

$(OBJECTS): $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<

clean: ; $(RM) $(DEPS) $(OBJECTS)

include $(DEPS)

$(MAKEFILE_LIST): ;
%:: %,v
%:: RCS/%,v
%:: RCS/%
%:: s.%
%:: SCCS/s.%
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your executable to be called "foo", add this rule to your makefile (and make it the first rule if you want it to be the default):

```
foo: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(LINKER_FLAGS) $^ -o $@
```

(Also note that in your `$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o` rule you have the `-c` flag twice, and a linker flag that does nothing. And you might want to update your `clean` rule to remove the executable.)